# Java BigInteger pow with an int base

Tags: java

I'm probably missing something and kinda rusted out this sort of thing, I was wondering what is the best way to implement `2^Biginteger` into a variable? I'm sure it's a simple question. This is to aid in figuring out a 2-pseudoprime. (Basically to see if `2^N-1 = 1` mod N or not).

Comment: Are you sure that `long` is not enough?

Comment: It is not enough alas.

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand you, you want to do something like this:

```
 BigInteger bigExp = ...  some really large value
 BigInteger pow = BigInteger.valueOf(2).pow(bigExp);
```

Unfortunately, that won't work.

As you noted, there is no `pow` overload that takes a `BigInteger` argument.  And when you think about it, such a method would be problematic.

The value of 2<sup>N</sup> is a value with N significant bits when represented in binary.  If is larger than will fit into an `int`, then that means `N` is 2<sup>31</sup> or more.  Or converting to bytes, that is 2<sup>28</sup> bytes or 0.25 Gigabytes.  For a single number.

That isn't *impossibly* large.  It should be possible to represent numbers that big, even in a 32 bit JVM.  The problem is that any `BigInteger` arithmetic operation is liable to generate another one of these monsters.  Just creating a number of this size is going to copy 0.25 Gigabytes, and operations like multiplication and division ... which are O(N^2) for N bit numbers ... are going to take "forever".

Having said that, there would be ways to generate numbers that size.  For example, you could allocate a huge byte array (which default initializes to zero), set the appropriate byte to contain a 1 bit, and then use `BigInteger(byte[])` to construct the monster number.

Comment: So if I have this right I should use the BigInteger.toByteArray(); to turn the Biginteger into a byte array and then from there subtract one and then utilize that to see if its the same as 1 mod N or not?

Answer (score 0):

As @StephenC points out, these numbers will be too unwieldy.

But

> to see if 2^N-1 = 1 mod N or not

You don't need to calculate 2^X.  You can calculate 2^X mod N. A much smaller number.

```
 BigInteger.valueOf(2).modPow(n.subtract(ONE), n);
```

Comment: n.subtract(ONE) Doesn't seem to be able to take an int. and create a Big int of one doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: @marcoquezada - Read the javadoc, read the javadoc.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#ONE